# How To store grep data in a variable so that it can we used later on?

Tags: shell

I wrote the code as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var
grep ec2_name: *.txt >tempStore
```

The data is not being stored in tempStore and when run there is no output.

I want to have all the files that contains the ec2_name and after that all file I want to store in tempStore.

Comment: What is the expected behavior of your program ? Do you want the list of all files containing "ec2_name" in their filenames ?

Comment: yes and that is achieving by using following code:-#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var
grep ec2_name: *.txt  but when i adding > besides of *.txt for storing the data its not working

Comment: Does it work with just `ls *.txt | grep "ec2_name" > tempStore` ?

Comment: Either you will separate commands with `;` or you will just use `grep 'ec2_name:' /home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var/*.txt >tempStore`

Comment: Sorry, have edited my comment, clicked "send" before fixing it

Comment: no i tried with this ...but the point is that i want to fetch the files that is present the above directory that i have mentioned  with .txt extension and i want to store in a variable

Comment: `grep -l` will print the filenames. See `man grep`

Comment: grep 'ec2_name:' /home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var/*.txt >tempStore yes its working .....thanks  George Vasiliou

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you want all the *.txt* files located in a specific directory and which names contains "ec2_name" to be stored in a bash variable.

Here is a possible solution

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var;

# mylist contains all files
mylist="`ls *.txt | grep ec2_name`";

# you can iterate over files with for-loop
for file in $mylist; do
    echo "file: $file";
done;
```

Correct me if I haven't understood your question

**edit:** simplified code

Comment: thanks..xdrm-brackets its really means a lot guys... i tried with your code :-#!/bin/bash

mydir="/home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var";

# mylist contains all files
mylist="`ls $mydir/*.txt | grep "ec2"`";

# you can iterate over files with for-loop
for file in $mylist; do
    echo "file: $file";
done;  but its giving info only one file as follows:- 
root@ip-172-31-45-152:/home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell# sh test4.sh
file: /home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var/test-ec2-linux.yml.txt
and in EC2-Var directory there are 4 files of .txt extenstion.

Comment: You don't need a for loop to print file names. `grep -l 'ec2' /full/path/to/*.txt` will do it at once for you

Comment: The loop was only a means to show how to use the variable. It is not an "actual" part of the solution.

Comment: and when i am looping through it i m getting follwoing error :- test5.sh: 9: test5.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable in the following code:-#!/bin/bash
grep 'ec2_name:' /home/ubuntu/MouniKaShell/newfolder/dev/EC2-Var/*.txt >tempStore
echo `cat tempStore`
awk  '{ print $2 }' tempStore > output
echo 'cat output'
#cat output
echo "enter ec2_name "
read b
for((i=0;i<4;i++));
do
if [[ $b == "${output[i]}" ]];
then
echo "sample"
fi
done

Comment: Update your question to add formatted code but avoid sending more than one line of code in comments, it is impossible to read and understand. Some really wants to help you but for them to find a solution, it has to feature a clear question, with expected behavior vs. what you got and explain what you already tried.